# Question about the iPod Touch and iPad

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can the iPod Touch/iPad be considered a portable game console?

Comment: Belongs on meta?

Comment: @Ed: this is already covered and seems to be allowed on the main site under http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion yes. The variety of games and accessibility of the App Store make it a worth opponent of the PSP and the DS. My iPod Touch is my main gaming console.

Comment: Agreed, though we would probably want to keep it game related only.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do something other than play games on my iPad...

Comment: yeah... what other use has an iPad... you can't even listen to music while writing an email, or write email while listning to music </sarcasm>